# Build grafana from source Win-32bit (Searching for -lmingwex and -lmingw32)

Tags: go, gcc, cygwin, grafana

I have successfully built grafana from source for Windows 64-bit (GOARCH=amd64) and now i am trying to build it for windows 32-bit (GOARCH=386). Unfortunately i get the following error via Cygwin

```
searching for -lmingwex
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gc
c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when
searching for -lmingw32
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gc
c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when
searching for -lmingw32
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gc
c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when
searching for -lmingw32
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-
w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
exit status 1
```

For your own convenience, i also attach the following
[image]

Any idea that could assist me?

Regards

Comment: `skipping incompatible` suggests to me that you somehow try to use 64-bit libraries with the 32-bit compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to build it in Win-32 bit platform via installation of [tdm-gcc](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/download/) (32-bit only) and of course by using the following command

[image]

Regards